# Setting screen boundaries within a class

Tags: c#, class, xna, screen

So this is my first time working creating classes and setting up a parent child hierarchy.

In this class I've created a crosshair and then a playership within the *PlayerClasses.cs*. I managed to set my screen boundaries for the crosshair without a problem. And I thought using the same code in the `Updateme` for the ship would work. But it hasn't and I'm a little miffed as to why.

The trouble is I don't know what rectangle I'm calling. I presumed it would be as I've coded it `m_rect`, but it doesn't seem to work, help would be appreciated!

Below I've posted the section of code that isn't working followed by the whole code for the class.

```cs
public void Updateme(KeyboardState kb, GameTime gt)
{
    m_velocity = Vector2.Zero;

    if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
        m_velocity.Y = -1;
    if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
        m_velocity.Y = 1;
    if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        m_velocity.X = -1;
    if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        m_velocity.X = 1;

    m_position += m_velocity;

    // Extra Task 1 PlayerShip Screenbounds
    #region Extra task1

    if (m_rect.X > 800)
    {
       m_rect.X = 800;
    }

    if (m_rect.X < 0)
    {
        m_rect.X = 0;
    }

    if (m_rect.Y > 480)
    {
        m_rect.Y = 480;
    }

    if (m_rect.Y < 0)
    {
        m_rect.Y = 0;
    }

    #endregion Extra task1
```

Whole code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Sidescroller;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Sidescroller
{
    class Crosshair : StaticGraphic 
    {
        private Color m_tint;
        private Vector2 m_center;

        public Crosshair(Rectangle rect, Texture2D txr, Color tint)
            : base(rect, txr)
        {
            m_tint = tint;
            m_center = new Vector2(m_rect.Width / 2, m_rect.Height / 2);
        }

        public void Updateme(MouseState ms_curr)
        {
            m_rect.X = ms_curr.X;
            m_rect.Y = ms_curr.Y;

            // Extra Task 1 Crosshair Red When Clicked
            #region Extra task1

            if (ms_curr.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                m_tint = Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
                m_tint = Color.Green;
            }

            #endregion Extra task1

            // Extra Task 2 Rotating Crosshair
            #region Extra task2


            #endregion Extra task2

            // Extra Task 3 Crosshair Screenbounds
            #region Extra task3

            if (m_rect.X > 800)
            {
                m_rect.X = 800;
            }

            if (m_rect.X < 0)
            {
                m_rect.X = 0;
            }

            if (m_rect.Y > 480)
            {
                m_rect.Y = 480;
            }

            if (m_rect.Y < 0)
            {
                m_rect.Y = 0;
            }

            #endregion Extra task3

        }

        public override void drawme(SpriteBatch sBatch)
        {
            sBatch.Draw(m_txr, m_rect, null, m_tint, 0, m_center, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
        }

    }

    class PlayerShip : MotionGraphic
    {
        public PlayerShip(Rectangle rect, Texture2D txrShip)
            : base(rect, txrShip)
        {

        }

        public void Updateme(KeyboardState kb, GameTime gt)
        {
            m_velocity = Vector2.Zero;

            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                m_velocity.Y = -1;
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                m_velocity.Y = 1;
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                m_velocity.X = -1;
            if (kb.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                m_velocity.X = 1;

            m_position += m_velocity;

            // Extra Task 1 PlayerShip Screenbounds
            #region Extra task1

            if (m_rect.X > 800)
            {
                m_rect.X = 800;
            }

            if (m_rect.X < 0)
            {
                m_rect.X = 0;
            }

            if (m_rect.Y > 480)
            {
                m_rect.Y = 480;
            }

            if (m_rect.Y < 0)
            {
                m_rect.Y = 0;
            }

            #endregion Extra task1

        }
    }




}
```

Comment: I replaced the ships code with the below code and it works. I don't fully understand why but it does. 




            if (m_position.X > 800)
            {
                m_position.X = 800;
            }

            if (m_position.X < 0)
            {
                m_position.X = 0;
            }

            if (m_position.Y > 480)
            {
                m_position.Y = 480;
            }

            if (m_position.Y < 0)
            {
                m_position.Y = 0;
            }

So the ships rectangle is m_position not m_rect? Hmmm don't understand!

Comment: Just an ammendment to my last comment. I forgot to take the sprites Width and Height off of the maximum X and Y values. So for anyone else struggling with this issue remember that the sprite draws from the top left side and so this code will work but it won't breach the boundaries until it is already off screen. So my sprite is 30 by 12, therefore I take 30 off width and 12 off height. Giving me a boundary of 770 and 468.

Comment: If you have to add code just edit your question, don't add unclear comments.

Comment: Anyway, in your `Crosshair` constructor you use `m_rect` and I don't know what it is. And what's that `Rectangle rect` parameter?